# What does this sed expression from todo.sh do?

Tags: regex, shell, sed

**What does the sed expression: `G; s/\n/&&/; /^\([ ~-]*\n\).*\n\1/d; s/\n//; h; P` do?** Exactly what does it match and how does it match it?

It's from [todo.sh](https://github.com/ginatrapani/todo.txt-cli/blob/master/todo.sh). In context:

```
archive()
{
    #defragment blank lines
    sed -i.bak -e '/./!d' "$TODO_FILE"                     ## delete all empty lines
    [ $TODOTXT_VERBOSE -gt 0 ] && grep "^x " "$TODO_FILE"  ## if verbose mode print completed tasks..
    grep "^x " "$TODO_FILE" >> "$DONE_FILE"                ## append completed tasks to $DONE_FILE
    sed -i.bak '/^x /d' "$TODO_FILE"                       ## delete completed tasks
    cp "$TODO_FILE" "$TMP_FILE"


    sed -n 'G; s/\n/&&/; /^\([ ~-]*\n\).*\n\1/d; s/\n//; h; P' "$TMP_FILE" > "$TODO_FILE"


    ## G;                       Add a newline
    ## s/\n/&&/;                Substitute newline with && (two newlines?)
    ## /^\([ ~-]*\n\).*\n\1/d;  Delete duplicate lines???
    ## s/\n//                   Remove newlines
    ## h                        Hold: copy pattern space to buffer
    ## P                        Print first line of pattern space
    if [ $TODOTXT_VERBOSE -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "TODO: $TODO_FILE archived."
    fi
}
```

Comment: The explanation is right in the comments after the sed, isn't it?

Comment: @Peter: I added those comments myself while trying to decipher the sed expression. It's my progress so far... The third segment is a doozy (backreference on the right hand side?), and I'm not sure how all the segments end up interacting with each other.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, you've got some of the story already. Recall that the sed expression is executed for each input line. So the `G` at the beginning appends the contents of the hold space to the current line (with a newline in between). The contents of the hold space is empty initially but expanded by the `h` command at the end of each input cycle.

Then `s/\n/&&/` duplicates the *first* newline only, the one between the current line and what was grabbed from the hold space. This is in preparation for the next command. `/^\([ -~]*\n\).*\n\1/` indeed matches if the current line is identical to a line in the hold space:
    `^\([ -~]*\n\)` matches a line at the beginning of the buffer¹
        *Note that this matches only if the line contains only printable ASCII characters.*
        *If your system supports locales, `^\([[:print:]]*\n\)` would be better.*
    `.*\n` matches at least one subsequent line
    `\1` matches a line identical to the first line
The extra newline added by the previous `s` command takes care of the case when the duplicate is the very first line from the hold space. The point of the `\n\1` is to “anchor” the duplicate at the beginning of a line, otherwise `bar` would be considered a duplicate of `foobar`. If the current line is a duplicate, the `d` command discards it and execution branches to the next line.

If the current line is not a duplicate, `s/\n//` discards that extra newline (again, no `g` modifier, so only the first newline is removed). Then the `h` command results in the hold space containing what it contained before, with the current line prepended. Finally `P` prints the current input line.

Ok, now what does the hold space contain? It starts empty, then gets each successive line prepended unless it's a duplicate. So the hold space contains the input lines, in reverse order, minus the duplicates.

¹  <sub>Uh, I don't know how you did that, but that should be `[ -~]`, not `[ ~-]` which wouldn't make any sense.</sub>

---

Here's another way of doing this, if you have a POSIX-conforming set of tools ([Single Unix v2](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/) is good enough).

```
<"$TMP_FILE" \
nl -s: |              # add line numbers
sort -t: -k2 -u |     # sort, ignoring the line numbers, and remove duplicates
sort -t: -k1 -n |     # sort by line number
cut -d: -f2-          # cut out the line numbers
```

---

Oh, you wanted to do this legibly and concisely? Just use awk.

```
<"$TMP_FILE" awk '!seen[$0] {++seen[$0]; print}'
```

If the current line hasn't been seen yet, mark it as seen, and print it.

Note that like the sed method, the awk method essentially stores the whole file in memory. The method above using `sort` has the advantage that only `sort` needs to keep more than one line of input at a time, and it's designed for this.

Of course, if you don't care about the order of the lines, it's as simple as `sort -u`.

Comment: Thanks for the clear walk-through! Can you explain in more detail how `/^\([ ~-]*\n\).*\n\1/` works?

Comment: I’ve got a lot of respect for anybody who can unravel `sed` scripts. Hm, what’s `nl`? That’s not a standard Unix command, is it? It’s not on either of OpenBSD or Mac OS X (FreeBSD).  Oh wait, I just found one on Solaris. SystemV then?

Comment: @tchrist: Huh, so that's yet another bit of POSIX that OpenBSD lacks. `nl` might not have been in V7, but it's in [Single UNIX v2](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xcu/nl.html), [FreeBSD 4.5](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=nl&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+4.5-RELEASE), [NetBSD 1.4](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=nl&sektion=1&manpath=NetBSD+1.4), [OSX 10.4](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/10.4/man1/nl.1.html), Linux (GNU) since I don't know when.

Comment: I’ve used BSD since PDP-11’s, and I’ve never heard of `nl`. …time passes… Ok, it was made part of dot-2 in 2004 with the [“Issue 6” update of 1003.2](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/xrat/xcu_chap01.html). That’s like yesterday — heck, I dunno if I’ve even *rebooted* since then. :) More seriously, that’s all part of the XSI extension set, which is not mandatory: *“A POSIX-conformant system **may** support the XSI extensions of the Single UNIX Specification.”*

Comment: @Gilles: apparently `[ ~-]` works... It was actually changed from `[ -~]` to fix a bug: https://github.com/harding/todo.txt-cli/commit/294e2ac9a49ed492d740445847188d77cd8f3c74

Comment: @Leftium: That's weird. `[ ~-]` is supposed to match only space, `~` or `-`, and that's what happens on my machine as well (the `[ ~-]` version only rejects duplicate lines consisting entirely of these three characters).

Comment: @Gilles: That commit must have fixed one bug while introducing another. sed stopped dying with "Invalid range end," but duplicate lines are no longer properly deleted. Also gives me an excuse for not being able to fully decipher the sed expression^^

Answer (score 2):

After Gilles presented his excellent answer I found [Famous Sed One-Liners Explained](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/sed-one-liners-explained-part-three/), which includes this exact sed expression; adding here for reference:

> **70. Delete duplicate, nonconsecutive lines from a file.**

```
sed -n 'G; s/\n/&&/; /^\([ -~]*\n\).*\n\1/d; s/\n//; h; P'
```

> This is a very tricky one-liner. It
>   stores the unique lines in hold buffer
>   and at each newly read line, tests if
>   the new line already is in the hold
>   buffer. If it is, then the new line is
>   purged. If it's not, then it's saved
>   in hold buffer for future tests and
>   printed.
>
> A more detailed description - at each
>   line this one-liner appends the
>   contents of hold buffer to pattern
>   space with "G" command. The appended
>   string gets separated from the
>   existing contents of pattern space by
>   "\n" character. Next, a substitution
>   is made to that substitutes the "\n"
>   character with two "\n\n". The
>   substitute command "s/\n/&&/" does
>   that. The "&" means the matched
>   string. As the matched string was
>   "\n", then "&&" is two copies of it
>   "\n\n". Next, a test "/^([
>   -~]*\n).*\n\1/" is done to see if the contents of group capture group 1 is
>   repeated. The capture group 1 is all
>   the characters from space " " to "~"
>   (which include all printable chars).
>   The "[ -~]*" matches that. Replacing
>   one "\n" with two was the key idea
>   here. As "([ -~]*\n)" is greedy
>   (matches as much as possible), the
>   double newline makes sure that it
>   matches as little text as possible. If
>   the test is successful, the current
>   input line was already seen and "d"
>   purges the whole pattern space and
>   starts script execution from the
>   beginning. If the test was not
>   successful, the doubled "\n\n" gets
>   replaced with a single "\n" by
>   "s/\n//" command. Then "h" copies the
>   whole string to hold buffer, and "P"
>   prints the new line.